# ERP (Oracle) real time backup

Tags: oracle, mirroring, storage, dataguard

I work in a small company, that runs an ERP that holds about 600MB of data.  My task at hand is, to find a way to always have real time backup of the erp (Oracle 11g) that can be retrieved easily (so that the company keeps working).  Right now, the erp is hosted on one IBM Server (Windows 2008 R2), and we keep backups of the previous day.  The company that supports the erp, says "Go IBM Storage, it is awesome and we know how to do it", but my question is: is an IBM Storage device really safe? Sure, it has 2 controllers, 2 psus, disks in raid, but can i depend on it? if something happens on the device itself (not some disk, or a psu, or even the pc that will access it itself as there will be 2 of them), ain't the company out of business (without even the backups of the previous day?).  I found and proposed to the support company the Active Data Guard (Oracle software for data mirroring), but they don't use it at all (my guess is that it is cheaper than storage solution and they won't make much by selling just one pc and some software).  What would you suggest?

Comment: What are the REAL requirements? How much data can you deal with losing? How much downtime can you suffer when you need to failover/restore? You have to think about the ways that the original database is likely to fail. With decent storage, it's going to be a host failure that most impacts you, not a disk failure. Active Data Guard is EXPENSIVE. Are you really running Enterprise Edition for 600Mb of data?!

Comment: Data loss and time to restore have to be at a minimum, you see, it may be 600MB of data, but it's a really profitable corp. 
Host failure? you mean the pc that runs the erp? I won't mind for pc failure as there will be two in this case. 
What do yo mean that Data Guard is expensive? 
I know that it's a bit overkill to run like this (espescially when we are talking about an old erp), but it's not my setup.  The company that supports the ERP tends to do all sorts of overkills in hardware just to sell it as i have come to realize the past 1.5 month that i work here.

Answer (score 2):

Fault-tolerant storage, a stand-by database (Data Guard in your case), and the database backup are three different solutions to different types of problems. Depending on how much downtime you can afford, you may need to implement all three.